# I want to move the activity, after being pressed, the project application exits independently, please help me

Tags: android

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginMainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);                         startActivity(mainIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordind the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity), to start a new `Activity` you need to pass the `context` and start it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginMainActivity.class);
    
startActivity(intent);
```